# WPF "Value of type 'Grid' cannot be converted to 'Control'

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to create a Function.

One of the parameters is `Control` (`System.Windows.Controls.Control`)

Some of the controls as `Buttons` or `TextBoxes` are acceptable.

Although `Grid` or `Images` return an error.

[image: failed code]

All of them are Controls and belong in the Namespace `System.Windows.Controls`

Why some of these are accepted and some are not?

Comment: "All of them are Controls". No, Grid isn't derived from Control

Comment: Thank you ASh for your reply. Is there a way to include all controls included those who is not derived?

Comment: Control is not common base class for TextBox, Button, Image and Grid.. Read the docs about each of them and find a common base class

Comment: Please define what you mean by "all controls". As mentioned, a `Grid` is not a control. It's a panel. Perhaps you want your method to accept a more common base type like for example `FrameworkElement` or `DependencyObject` instead of `Control`.

Comment: Thank you Both! You are right! @mm8 I will use `FrameworkElement` instead of `Control`.

Comment: Odd thing - for the last ten years I have used a method to register a control for WPF apps. Just built a new app and it ran fine for days, then suddenly started to throw that error for buttons and other items - changing to FrameworkElement fixed it, but to just start out of the blue is really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why some of these are accepted and some are not?

Because some types are indeed not controls. `Grid` is for example not a control. It's a `Panel`.

You probably want your method to accept a more common base type like for example `FrameworkElement` or `DependencyObject` instead of `Control`.